# Is it possible to print out the equation of motion of a SimMechanics model?

Tags: matlab, simulink, simmechanics

I want to know if it is possible to get the equation of motion from a SimMechanics model which I imported from Solidworks? And if it is possible how can I do it?

Comment: how come Matlab is tagged here?

Comment: @Benoit_11 SimMechanics is a Simulink Toolbox which is (as you know) a Matlab Toolbox - however @ Joao I'd guess the number of people reading that question and knowing about SimMechanics tends to zero.

Comment: Short answer: no, sorry.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to extract a closed form equation from Simmechanics. Cf. Simulink: you perform operations on signals and plot the results, but you don't get any equations.